# Garage roller shutter door opening by itself

Tags: garage, garage-door

It has a remote control switch and brand is Centurion Australia.
I closed but it opens by itself after few hours.

I recently tried to add a duplicate remote key but that was incompatible and so the coding failed. Initially I thought it was due to that, so removed the batteries from it . But this also doesn't fix the issue

Any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: Is there moisture or a bug in the control box shorting contacts?

Comment: No it is not. Also It is pretty new only couple years old

Comment: Bugs can get in after hours or days even...

Comment: Has one of your neighbors also got a remote door and that is triggering yours?

Comment: At a guess, if this started happening only after you did that, attempting to add the other remote somehow got your opener listening to someone else's remote, inadvertently. Find (online, if you don't have it on paper) the manual for your opener, and look for a procedure to make it forget all remotes, and re-pair only with your remote, or similar. You might also need to change the code your current remote is using.

Comment: @Ecnerwal sounds like a good answer to me...

Answer (score 2):

I was not fully aware what happened when I tried to code an incompatible remote key bought for spare from Ebay..

What I did is changed the existing code and that seems fixed the issue. I have to copy this new code to all the existing keys, but that was easy.

[This video also helped..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paxQLvbimnc)